# Find $\mathbb C[x,y,z]^{S_3}$ using Hilbert's Basis Theorem?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-actions, invariant-theory

Here is the Exercise 2.2.3 from An Invitation to Algebraic Geometry.

> Let the group $S_{3}$ act on the polynomial $\mathbb C[x,y,z]$. Find the ring of invariant polynomials.

Since $S_{3}$ contains only 6 elements, it is not hard to solve the problem by considering all permutations. However, the exercise is under chapter Hilbert's Basis Theorem. I don't know how they are related.

So, my question is, is there any way to solve this problem quickly by using the theorem?

Comment: I don't really see how Hilbert's Basis Theorem helps you, but there is a nice general theorem at work here: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial#Fundamental_theorem_of_symmetric_polynomials.

Comment: My guess is that the relationship is historical in nature. Hilbert's basis theorem shows that the ideal corresponding to the ring of invariants is finitely generated, a major open problem at Hilbert's time. The basis theorem is non-constructive however, whereas you're essentially asked to find it.